# How to use local ssh key in vagrant ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys

How to set Vagrant to use local ssh keys for github. I have workign ssh keys on my local machine and created vagrant machine, and i want to use my local ssh keys in my vagrant ubuntu machine. How can i achieve this?

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
   # stuff
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

this does not working for me, any suggestions?

Comment: so you want to use the same ssh key that you have for github to connect on your vagrant instance ? or you just want to connect to github from your vagrant box ?